# MySQL: Collect records from multiple queries into one result

Tags: sql, mysql

I am looking to create a SQL query that collects the results from multiple queries.

I would like to apply a random sort order and return a limited number of the records.

The queries will all return the same field ("`RefCode`" in this example), but will have different FROM and WHERE statements.

See an example below of some possible queries:

```
SELECT PD.RefCode
FROM ((PD 
INNER JOIN P ON PD.PrdFK = P.PrdID) 
INNER JOIN PR ON PR.ChildCatFK = P.ChildCatFK)
WHERE PR.ParentCatFK = 6

SELECT PD.RefCode
FROM (PR 
INNER JOIN PD ON PR.PrdDetFK = PD.PrdDetID)
WHERE PR.ChildCatFK = 14
```

I have tried doing this using various techniques (i.e. `UNION`) but have not been able to get the right method.

The random sorting and limiting of records (Using `RAND()` and `LIMIT 0,10`) is not essential but it would be great to have.

Is this possible or do I need to create each query separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a UNION to combine the queries.  Wrap them in a subquery so you can ORDER BY and LIMIT the result:

```
SELECT RefCode
FROM (
    SELECT PD.RefCode
    FROM PD 
    INNER JOIN P ON PD.PrdFK = P.PrdID
    INNER JOIN PR ON PR.ChildCatFK = P.ChildCatFK
    WHERE PR.ParentCatFK = 6

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PD.RefCode
    FROM PR 
    INNER JOIN PD ON PR.PrdDetFK = PD.PrdDetID
    WHERE PR.ChildCatFK = 14

) subquery
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 10
```